# JMS Serializer selective serialization

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

PHP, Symfony, JMSSerializerBundle.

I want to serialize the `User` object inside `Organization` object to its ID, but when the `User` object belongs to other objects use default serialization.

```
public class Organization {
   // type is User   
   $user;  -> "123123"
...
}

public class Other {
   // type is User   
   $user;  -> "{id: 123123, name: John, ...}"
...
}
```

Is it possible with reasonable effort?

Comment: Hi. Can you please accept my answer if it was helpful, or propose some changes if needed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could exclude `User` object from serialization, and add a virtual property that will return user ID (you can call it userId, user or whatever you want).

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\VirtualProperty;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Exclude;

public class Organization {

   /**
    * ...
    * @Exclude
    */ 
    $user;

  /**
   * @VirtualProperty
   * @SerializedName("user")
   */
   public function getUserId()
   { 
      return $this->user->getId(); 
   }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I created a custom type for this purpose, but your answer, in my opinion, is more clear, so I accepted it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! You could write your solution inside the original question. It may be helpful :)